# How to modify context for child fields in graphql-ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have query like this:

```
query {
  organizations {
    id
    name
    itemA {
      fieldA
      fieldB
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```json
"data": {
  "organizations": [
    {
      "id": 123, 
      "name": "first org",
      "itemA": {
        "fieldA": "some value A",
        "fieldB": "other value B",
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 321, 
      "name": "other org",
      "itemA": {
        "fieldA": "other value A",
        "fieldB": "value B",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

One user have access to multiple organizations, but with different access rights for each org.

I need to have organization.id when `fieldA` and `fieldB` are resolved to validate access.

I tried to use `context.merge_scoped!(organiozation_id: org.id)` in resolver for a field, that returns single org.
Looks like it do what I need, child fields received correct value in `context` but I'm not sure. There is no documentation for that method and for `scoped_context` in general.

Also, if `scoped_context` is what I need, how can I set it for a list of items?

---

UPD: sample query

```
query {
  organizations { // I need to pass item of this list to resolver of ItemA
    someModel{
      otherModel {
        itemA // access depened on organization`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature was documented in newer version:
https://graphql-ruby.org/queries/executing_queries.html#scoped-context

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I got your problem, but I think what you need should be "transparent" to GQL.

You need two things to correctly list "items" for an organization: 1. which organization and 2. who is asking:

```
# type organization
def itemA
  object # this is 1, the organization, current node in the graph
    .get_fields_accessible_by(context[:who_is_asking]) # this is requirement 2
end
```

As you can see, there seems not to be a reason to manipulate context at all. (Unless I missed the point completely, so feel free to amend your question to clarify).

Comment: Access management is done per organization. 
Query may take data for multiple organizations. `itemA` may be deeper, not directly in the organization.
Added sample query to question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try :

```
context[:organisation] = object #set this value in your organisation model
```

access it in another model using, `current[:organisation]`

Additionally, you can create helper method

something like

```
def current_organisation
  context[:current_organisation]
end
```

Thanks